# can i use camera.parameters possible camera flip?

Tags: android, camera

I want `Camera Preview` left and right reverse. (Mirror mode)

before, I try use `TextureView`

```
private Camera mCamera;
private TextureView mTextureView;

@Override 
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
matrix.postTranslate(width, 0);
mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
```

this source camera preview mirror mode ok.

but I want not use `TextureView` only framelayout.

perhaps, is possible camera preview reverse only use `Camera.Parameters()?`

if is not possible. how to camera flip on framelayout?